# Passing current page URL via hidden input field within form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the URL of a current page via a hidden field so that I can redirect back to that page after the form's input has been handled. I've tried using javascript:location.href, however it looks as though it'll pass that as a literal string.

```
<input type="url" id="location" name="location" value="javascript:location.href" hidden />
```

When viewing the page source, I can see that the value of this input box is "javascript:location.href" rather than the page's URL. Any ideas here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can access the element in Javascript and change the value there

```
document.getElementById('location').value = location.href;
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6zxD5/

Comment: That would be possible, but you would need to put this script on the bottom of the page or it will get called before the DOM tree is ready.

Comment: yes, but  I actually don't see this as a problem. Separating js from html tags isn't the worst thing to do, if you ask me. :) Unless you're doing angular :D

Comment: Okay, if you want that, `window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('location').value = location.href;}` would be even better.

Comment: One doesn't have to wait until window is loaded (including all images etc) in order to query the dom, right?

Comment: Well, it is the first callback on page load, so yes you have to. Look at  this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14128765/1024057

Comment: PTAL at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/js-window-onload-vs-jquery-document-ready

Comment: I don't see the OP using jQuery.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is only available in "modern" browsers.

Comment: which of the browsers do you consider "modern"? IE9? And we didn't even specify the constraints for our discussion. We're both right, ok ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works that way. You could just use the onload callback to insert it when the page is completely loaded:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('location').value = document.location.href">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your document containing the form is already a PHP file , you can do

```
 $yourPath = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And in your html you would do

```
echo '<input type="url" id="location" name="location" value="'.$yourPath.'" hidden />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to set the value of the hidden field:

```
document.getElementById('location').value = window.location.href;
```

Example:

**https://jsfiddle.net/moogs/mhjh0je3/**

Since you also tagged PHP, here's the PHP version:

```
<input type="hidden" id="location" name="location" value="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

Comment: You missed the dot to concatenate the strings in the echo.